# Client Certification exception when accessing Azure Key Vaults

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, client-certificates, azure-keyvault

this one has kept me busy for the past day.

I'm trying to use Azure Key Vaults service from my .net core 2.2 app using a certification as security.

I'm installing the certificate within the same code on the startup of an application, using a base64 encoded string as input parameter.

When installing in the `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` (and running VS as admin) the application works fine and the secrets are retrieved.

When using `StoreLocation.CurrentUser`, the application throws a `NullReferenceException` when trying to retrieve the secrets from the vault.

```
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.CryptographyHelper.SignWithCertificate(String message, X509Certificate2 certificate)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.JsonWebToken.Sign(IClientAssertionCertificate credential)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.ClientKey.AddToParameters(IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<SendTokenRequestAsync>d__64.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.<RunAsync>d__55.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext
....
```

I've seen people mentioning the same kind of exception back in 2017 when moving to .NET 4.7
([Here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/708) and [Here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/3521)).

I tried to run the application with various newer versions of the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory` package without success. From 3.14 to 3.19 it throws the same exception. From 4.3 onwards it's missing the `.Platforms` dll which is no longer provided by the package.

Finally, I fetched, compiled and ran the examples application from the [Extensions repository](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/9bc79b2f25a3724376d7af19617c33749a30ea3a/src/Configuration/Config.AzureKeyVault/samples) (which is also using `CurrentUser` location and I have the same exception.

I have not yet tried to run it on .NET Core 3.0. But I believe something is wrong with the initial writing.

I'm running out of further resources to investigate so I'm reaching out to the community :)

Below is the code as a simple sample app that I use to write/read the certificate.

```
dotnet .\Certificates.dll -- -c {cert-base64-encoded-string} -p {cert-password}
```

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{
    //// Using CommandLineParser
    var options = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args)
        .WithParsed(o =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(o.Certificate))
            {
                o.CertPassword = o.CertPassword ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("No certificate password provided.");

                var rawData = Convert.FromBase64String(o.Certificate);

                //// install certificate
                using (X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser, OpenFlags.ReadWrite))
                {
                    var cert = new X509Certificate2(rawData, o.CertPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
                    ThumbPrint = cert.Thumbprint;
                    store.Add(cert);
                }
            }
        });

    CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(configHost =>
        {
            using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
            {
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, ThumbPrint, false);

                configHost.AddAzureKeyVault(_vault, _key, certs.OfType<X509Certificate2>().Single());

            }
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: Is your application hosted as an app service ? vm ? kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: This example fails when just running local in VS under IIS Express. The final app will be running under linux in a Cloud Foundry environment, but with the same error. I don't think it's linked to the environment.

Comment: I mean you shouldn't install the cert when your application start but rather install it using some automation scripts. and based on your target host, there may be some better options. From VS I use `azure app authentication` to authenticate to KV and once deployed the application uses `managed identity ` which provides access to KV with no credentials.

Comment: I would agree with you. However I don't know Cloud Foundry, nor do I have access to all the admin features to figure out what is available. So while I'm trying to figure that out, I went for this hacking solution, just out of curiosity if it would work or not.
What does puzzle me is why this code works when storing in LocalMachine and not in CurrentUser. Putting aside that this may not be correct production code, I'd like to know now why technically it doesn't work :(

Comment: Btw, `managed identity` only works if your app is hosted in an Azure VM, which is not the case for me.

Comment: Are you running VS as an admin while using the `CurrentUser` store ? `managed identity` works on lots of services such as app service, vm, aks, logic app etc. I really don't know cloud foundry. I am gonna have a look at the documentation :-)

Comment: I ran both as admin and non-admin. I'm currently uploading my code to github, hoping it makes it easier for someone to reproduce. 
I mean that `managed identity` works only for apps deployed to Azure. Otherwise it's either with a secret key or a certificate (at least from what I understood :)). 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#sample-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was writing up the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/RRosier/Azure-Client-Certificates) file for this problem's example, I stumbled upon the solution.

It pains me to say that it was a human error...

I was passing in a wrong Base64String for the certificate. Probably one that I created earlier.

When passing in the correct generated string in the command, the code started working. You can see it on my [GitHub](https://github.com/RRosier/Azure-Client-Certificates)

In short it was failing because the certificate I used on the client did not correspond with the one on the server. Though the exception could be clearer.